# Mysql died and won't start

Tags: server, mysql, nginx

I am working on Ubuntu 12.10 server with nginx, mysql and unicorn installed. There is something wrong with Mysql and has stopped working.

Log message from `/var/log/mysql/error.log`

```
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x30000
mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x33)[0xb725de53]
mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x48c)[0xb710255c]
[0xb6dd0400]
mysqld(+0x5e4d72)[0xb73d7d72]
mysqld(+0x5cfc3b)[0xb73c2c3b]
mysqld(+0x5d15ba)[0xb73c45ba]
mysqld(+0x57107d)[0xb736407d]
mysqld(+0x59aa9d)[0xb738da9d]
mysqld(+0x52b0b0)[0xb731e0b0]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x6d4c)[0xb6db2d4c]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x5e)[0xb6b56d3e]
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I started mysql by enabling `innodb_force_recovery = 6` in `my.conf`. Since mysql service was launched, I created a dump file that I ran locally and managed to recovered lost data successfully.